# Getting one side of many to many from the other

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following three models linked up with a many to many relationship:

```
class TeamMember(models.Model):
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    report = models.ManyToManyField(Report, through='Owner')

class Report(models.Model):
    report_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    report_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    metric = models.ManyToManyField(Metric, through='MetricAssociation')

class Owner(models.Model):
    teammember = models.ForeignKey(TeamMember, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to build an object list of TeamMembers who belong to a specific report (dictated by owner) but am having trouble. Currently I have the ID of the report. I tried this, but it seems wrong:

```
owners = TeamMember.objects.filter(report__id=id).distinct().values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no field `name` in the `TeamMember` model. You have `member_name` instead

```
owners = TeamMember.objects.filter(report_id=id).distinct().values_list('member_name', flat=True)
```

On a side note, you can use `report_id` instead of `report__id` which requires a join operation.